# Transact-SQL Select with Name only

Tags: t-sql, select

Let's say I have the following two tables:

Fields

```
FieldID INT
FieldName NVARCHAR(50)
```

Values

```
FieldID INT
Value NVARCHAR(1000)
```

From the following stored procedure, how can I select only the values that are linked to a field which has the same FieldName than the one received as a parameter?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetValues]
@FieldName NVARCHAR(50)

AS SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Values]
WHERE ... ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select ...
From Fields As F
    Join Values As V
        On V.FieldID = F.FieldID
Where F.FieldName = @FieldName
```

Comment: Well that turned out to be simpler than I thought. Thanks.